# How to stop matplotlib from skipping gaps in data?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have this simple csv:

```
date,count
2020-07-09,144.0
2020-07-10,143.5
2020-07-12,145.5
2020-07-13,144.5
2020-07-14,146.0
2020-07-20,145.5
2020-07-21,146.0
2020-07-24,145.5
2020-07-28,143.0
2020-08-05,146.0
2020-08-10,147.0
2020-08-11,147.5
2020-08-14,146.5
2020-09-01,143.5
2020-09-02,143.0
2020-09-09,144.5
2020-09-10,143.5
2020-09-25,144.0
2021-09-21,132.4
2021-09-23,131.2
2021-09-25,131.0
2021-09-26,130.8
2021-09-27,130.6
2021-09-28,128.4
2021-09-30,126.8
2021-10-02,126.2
```

If I copy it into excel and scatter plot it, it looks like this

[image: excel]

This is correct; there should be a big gap in the middle (look carefully at the data, it jumps from 2020 to 2021)

However if I do this in python:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
data.plot.scatter('date', 'count')
plt.show()
```

It looks like this:

[image: matplotlib]

It evenly spaces them at the gap is gone. How do I stop that behavior? I tried to do

```
 plt.xticks = data.date
```

But that didn't do anything different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont exactly know the types of columns in data but it is probably beacuse tpye of 'date' column is string. So python does not understand comperable value. Before plotting try to convert it's type.

`data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'])`

Answer (score 0):

I've tested:

```
import io
import pandas as pd

txt = """
date,count
2020-07-09,144.0
2020-07-10,143.5
2020-07-12,145.5
2020-07-13,144.5
2020-07-14,146.0
2020-07-20,145.5
2020-07-21,146.0
2020-07-24,145.5
2020-07-28,143.0
2020-08-05,146.0
2020-08-10,147.0
2020-08-11,147.5
2020-08-14,146.5
2020-09-01,143.5
2020-09-02,143.0
2020-09-09,144.5
2020-09-10,143.5
2020-09-25,144.0
2021-09-21,132.4
2021-09-23,131.2
2021-09-25,131.0
2021-09-26,130.8
2021-09-27,130.6
2021-09-28,128.4
2021-09-30,126.8
2021-10-02,126.2"""

data = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(txt), sep=r",", parse_dates=["date"])

data.plot.scatter('date', 'count')
```

and the result is:

[image]

Two observations:

- date must be of `date` type, which is ensured by `parse_dates=["date"]` option
- importing `matplotlib.pyplot` is not necessary, because You used `pandas.DataFrame.plot.scatter` method.